# Should I spend all points at the "Prepare for the Journey Carefully" stage in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm a brand new player to Dwarf Fortress, and I've been looking at some beginners guides for starting a game. Although the guides tell you which skills it is worth investing in at the outset, they do not say anywhere if I should be spending the maximum amount of points that I can on my Dwarfs (this is after spending points on necessary items).

Should I be maxing out my points expenditure at the start, or do I need to save these for any reason?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All points left after embarking are lost, so use them all up.

Comment: You can never go wrong with more booze.

Comment: Better to make sure you have odd [i.e. number that fit + 1, including exactly 1 unit of anything you didn't otherwise buy] numbers of food/booze things, so you get more barrels.

Comment: @Random Good general practice, but it's less critical now since you can make "barrels" out of stone now instead of needing wood.

Answer (score 2):

it should be noted that the points can also be used both on dwarf skills and starting Items.

and yes you should use them all, as there is no point saving them.

if you have a few left over, concider a pair of breeding cats, Its a renewable meat source!

Comment: So are dogs, gophers, or really anything else you can get at embark, and you don't risk a **[catsplosion](http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/Catsplosion)**.

Comment: i dont mind the catsplosion, ive always managed to keep my cat numbers down to control about levels. byt yeah, i see your point.